# Cannot add tuple to list

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a list of tuples and cannot add them to a list. What causes this compile error? https://dotnetfiddle.net/vhR3vP

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;               
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
         List<Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string>> ExecutionsDetailsTuple =new  List<Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string>>(); // format executionid, symbol, quantity, price, tradedirection, orderaction, account, executiontime
        var person= Tuple.Create<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string>("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
        ExecutionsDetailsTuple.Add(person);
        
    }
}
```

compile error:

```
Compilation error (line 10, col 3): The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string>>.Add(System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string>)' has some invalid arguments
Compilation error (line 10, col 30): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.Tuple<string>>' to 'System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples should not be used in "production code" unless you deal with CLI or some other you get your input from some other language.

Because of Generics limitations in C# Tuples can have at most 8 generic values. And as per documentation: `The last element of an eight element Tuple must be a Tuple.`

To remove this error, convert this tuple to class, or convert your tuple so it uses a Tuple as a last element

Answer (score 2):

The return type of [`Tuple.Create<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=net-5.0#System_Tuple_Create__8___0___1___2___3___4___5___6___7_) with eight arguments is defined as:

```
Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,Tuple<T8>>
```

Notice the `Tuple<T8>` at the end. You think you would create a `Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>` instance with the `Tuple.Create()` method, but you are not.

As the number of generic parameters for the `Tuple` class is limited to eight, but there might be a requirement for more than eight values, the class is designed that way, that the 8th generic parameter must be a `Tuple` type. So the general structure will be: seven values plus an additional `Tuple` for the remaining values. Assuming you want to create a tuple of 25 values, you would build a chain of four `Tuple` instances (7+7+7+4).

When you want to use a tuple of eight values you have to change the type of your variable to `List<Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,Tuple<string>>>`.

Comment: i tried it but i have this error. how do i fix it if i have to have tuple as last row? https://dotnetfiddle.net/WSa0bl

Comment: @junkone There is no overload of [`Tuple.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=net-5.0) which takes nine arguments. You have to use the [`Tuple` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8.-ctor?view=net-5.0) to create a Tuple with eight values, where the 8th argument is a `Tuple` of two values. This will result in a tuple with 7+2 values.